# ASP.NET Ajax UpdatePanel flicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

Here's my code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="createChart" runat="server" OnClick="createChart_onClick"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="result" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="submit" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <!-- content -->
            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It works great. **My problem is that every now and then i see a white flicker sometime in between a request and a response.** It's a little annoying. Is this a common occurrence or could it be because of some other javascript on my page?

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome you will see a flicker with the UpdatePanel if your ajax response contains image urls. I noticed that this flicker did not occur with Safari, Firefox or Safari mobile but just Chrome and stopped when I removed `<img src="/images/photo.png" />` from ajax response content.

Comment: What is the down vote for? This is part of the solution for someone that finds this question and absolutely will be helpful to someone other than me.

Comment: I noticed the same thing in chrome. once i removed the img then the flicker disapeared.

Comment: Nice glad it helped, I knew it would help someone at some point, it is an annoying little diddy ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily improve it using `UpdateProgress`.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updLoading" DisplayAfter="2500" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updContent">
 <ProgressTemplate>
    <img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" align="middle" />
           Loading.  Please Wait...
 </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```