# Reducing redraw flickering on vb.net web application

Tags: vb.net, charts, flicker, redraw

I have a page on my web application which has a chart that gets retrieved using a timer. Is there a way to avoid the flickering everytime the chart is redrawn?
Since It's a web application, I guess the doublebuffer property isn't available, or at least I didn't find it and assumed it's webform related.
I would appreciate any help in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy but not suggested solution is to call the redraw manually and remove the event.

So you would remove the event handler and you call the function that redraws the chart when you think is required. i.e After the resize is done or after a value is changed etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a web application, I guess the redraw you are talking about is made using a browser page refresh.

If so, you should take a look at Microsoft Ajax Framework, and a UpdatePanel control to just refresh the specific chart part of your page. Should be smoother then.

http://www.asp.net/ajax

Comment: The chart is located inside an UpdatePanel. The flicker happens everytime the chart is bound to the datasource, in the timer event. I've replaced the chart control with an Ajax BarChart control, and the problem was solved, but I wonder if there's a way to do it with a chart control.

Comment: well then, I guess chart control takes too long to build.
maybe try this, if any help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085090/asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-flicker